# Google map doesnt work in IE Angular 2.0 project

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have Angular 2 project that needed google map and i have implemented simple google map using google api. I have put the google map api url in index.html
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey.

But this works only in chrome and firefox not in IE. I tried various solutions like having es5-shim/es5-shim.js referenced in index.html but still it doesnt work. My application itself not opening in IE. IF i comment the google api reference in index.html, the application works perfectly fine. 
I am going to remove this api reference and try private google map packages for angular2.0.

Why the google map api reference doesnt work? any pointers will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

try this.. its work for me...

Comment: yes i did this only. But I was trying to implement map using plain google api's.